# Estimating how much memory is available in PostgreSQL buffer caches?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am tuning my PostgreSQL db `effective_cache_size`. The PostgreSQL documentation references the  expected available memory in PostgreSQL buffer caches to calculate the expected memory available for disk caching. How do I estimate this? Is the `shared_buffers` the only memory allocated for the buffer caching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`effective_cache_size` represents the total memory of the machine minus what you know is used for something else than disk caching.

From Greg's Smith [5-Minute Introduction to PostgreSQL Performance](http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/postgresql/pg-5minute.htm):

> **effective_cache_size** should be set to how much memory is leftover for
>   disk caching after taking into account what's used by the operating
>   system, dedicated PostgreSQL memory, and other applications

`shared_buffers` is considered in this sentence as "dedicated PostgreSQL memory", but other than that, it's not correlated to `effective_cache_size`.

On Linux if you run `free` when your system is at its typical memory usage (all applications running and caches are warm), the `cached` field gives a good value for `effective_cache_size`.

If you use monitoring tools that produce graphs, you can look at the cached size for long period of times at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

One typical suggestion for a dedicated Postgres server is to set effective_cache_size to about 3/4 of your available RAM. A good tool to use for setting sane defaults is pgtune, which can be found here: https://github.com/gregs1104/pgtune